# Carousel card not working with the javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, codepen

Carousel not working please provide me guidelines to make it run.
also, if possible make it infinite load on horizontal scroll.
I tried but JavaScript is not working. Kindly provide me actual guidance to make it run.
https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/qBxqmYr

**Code**

```js
let currentScrollPosition = 0;
let scrollAmount = 320;

const sCont = document.querySelector(".storys-conatainer");
const hScroll = document.querySel ector(".horizontal-scroll");

let maxScroll = -sCont.offsetWidth + hScroll.offsetWidth;

function scrollHorizontally(val) {
  currentScrollPosition += (val * scrollAmount);

  sCont.style.left = currentScrollPosition + "px";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">


    <div class="horizontal-scroll">
      <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-left" onclick="scrollHorizontally(1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>

      <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-right" onclick="scrollHorizontally(-1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
      <div class="storys-container">
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRaibWeB6YHcbSZ05T8GEaAaxROO_JCdcYpjgU-rH_yS9IEduhj11ExA_yWVPKrTnqxJzg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="story-circle">
          <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There were some typos: https://codepen.io/sparxia/pen/ZErJOMN and curly brace missing.

Comment: Please recheck , limit of maxScroll ends at different position.

Comment: my hand is little tight in javascript, so i'm learning javascript and no other developer required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Bootstrap CSS library. It's pretty easy and simple and I guess you'll manage to get hold of it quickly. Everything is available in a pre-written form and you just need to make some minor changes like your images' *src* and that's all. Here is how it works.

To start with, you need to include Bootstrap’s production-ready CSS and JavaScript via CDN. Place the  tag in the  for Bootstrap CSS:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

, and the  tag for JavaScript bundle before the closing :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Of course, there are other ways to get started with Bootstrap. I assume the above the easiest, but if you're interested, you can read more about it on their webpage:

[Get started with Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/)

Anyway, next you just need to create a container for your carousel in your . You can do this by using bootstrap containers and columns. Here is a simple code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-6">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Again, if you're interested to know more about containers and columns, you can read these pages:

[Bootstrap Containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/containers/)
[Bootstrap Columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/columns/)

Finally, in order to make your carousel as quickly as possible, just copy and paste this pre-written code for carousel inside the  above:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0"
                            class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                            aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img src="./images/image01.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="./images/image02.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="./images/image03.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                        data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                        data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Of course you need to write down the correct *src* for your own images in the code snippet above. Again, if you'd like to know more about Bootstrap carousels and how to customize them, you can check their own webpage:

[Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/)

Hope you find this useful. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-6">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0"
                            class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                            aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img src="./images/image01.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="./images/image02.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="./images/image03.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                        data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                        data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i have used bootstrap for last 3 years but now i became lazy in core coding and want everything easily